# Aligning columns using CSS Grid

Tags: css-grid

In CSS Grid, I'm trying to find the best approach to aligning 3 columns, first column to the left, then second and third aligned to the right.

The second and third columns are both dynamic widths, so I need the third column to wrap to its contents width, then push the second columns content to the 'end', so both appear to fill to the right.

I have this working(ish), but I don't think its the best/correct approach. By setting `grid-template-columns` on the parent container to `200px 1fr`, both second and third columns align as I'd like, but I suspect this isn't the correct, or best approach.

Is anyone able to explain how this should be done?

Here is an example of how I have it currently working:

https://jsfiddle.net/Lb0qc7ep/

I am using CSS Grid as at different breakpoints, I need to rearrange the column orders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr auto auto;     
  grid-gap: 30px;
}
```

I removed all other CSS when I tried this

Comment: You will need to arrange the order if you want to manipulate it. But I think this is the best approach for aligning 1 left and 2 right.

You can also add a ``max-width`` to ``.item-2`` and ``.item-3`` to limit their width.

Comment: Thank you!! That makes so much more sense.